# error: Array required, but String found

Tags: java, arrays

I've declared public static arrays for name and id:

```
public static String[] name = new String[19];     
public static int[] id  = new int[19];
```

But `java compiler` says:

```
java:70: error: array required, but String found
java:71: error: array required, but int found
```

I don't know what's wrong. Is it how I declared the variables or in the method that I wrote?

```
public static boolean add(String name, int id, int i) 
{
    if (i < 20) {
        name[i] = name;
        id[i] = id;
        return true;
    }
    else if (i > 20) {
        for (int j = 0; j < id.length; j++) {
            if (id[j] == 0 && name[j].equals("null"))
                id[j] = id;
            name[j] = name; 
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a collision between the static `name` String array and the local `name` String variable passed to the `add` method.

The best solution would be to use different names. It would make the code much easier to understand.

If you still insist on using the same name, you can resolve the name collision by accessing the static array using the class name:

```
YourClassName.name[i]= name;
```

The same applies to your `id` int array and `id` int variable.

Answer (score 2):

Pay *close attention* to how you're using your variables.  `name` (inside of your method) is a `String`, but you're doing an array element access on it. with `i`.  The same is true for `id`; it is an `int`, but you're doing an array element access on it.

You're effectively shadowing your static variables, which causes confusion and heartache.

Consider renaming the parameters to your method, or using the class name to reference them.

Either:

```
public static boolean add (String theName , int theIds, int i)
```

or:

```
// for every usage of id and name as arrays
MyClass.name[i]= name;
MyClass.id[i]=id;
```